# If I am using a React app to make a Social Media site, how do I prevent other sites making API calls to my DB through the server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication

I know how to make an MVC style server/site, with protected routes that would re route unauth calls. But, I want to make a React app, so will the Auth need to be on the front end, to prevent components from displaying if they are protected?

If the auth is on the client side, what would I need to do to ensure that only authorised users can make api calls to my server/database? For example, if my user information is stored in mongo db and accessed through an api call to my server, from my react app, what would prevent someone using a direct url, as front end access would be protected by auth, but not back end? Do I have this set up incorrect?

Comment: you can specify a specific CORS domain, that is allow access from specific IP or DNS names,

Comment: So would that be in Mongo DB? Only allowing access to the database for requests which are made from the ip of where the react app is being hosted?

Comment: no your API, you cannot protect your DB from the client, anything can be decoded and changed in JavaScript